# Mathematica, convert string to number

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I imported a table in mathematica using Import["..file","table"] now I cant use the numbers in the table as they are in string formta, can someone please explain how can i convert them from string to number again?

Comment: `Import[.."Table"]` should handle numbers correctly to begin with. Can you show what the file looks like?

Answer (score 17):

Another approach is to use `Read`. This is useful if you have numbers in "E" form scientific notation:

```
    Read[StringToStream[#], Number] &/@{ "1" ,"1.5" , "1E-20" , "2.E10" }
```

{1, 1.5, 1.5*10^-20, 2.*10^10}

Note `ToExpression` gets these wrong:

```
    ToExpression /@ {"1", "1.5", "1.5E-20", "2.E10"}
```

{1, 1.5, -15.9226, 2. E10}

"1.5E-20" is evaluated as 1.5 * 2.71828-20
in the last case the "E10" is taken as a new symbol..

`ToExpression` is however faster if you can use it..

Edit...per comment `StringToStream` leaves the streams open.  This closes the streams:

```
 stringToNumber[s_String] := 
         Module[{str = StringToStream@s, n}, n = Read[str, Number]; Close@str; n]
 stringToNumber /@ {"1", "1.5", "1E-20", "2.E10"}
```

Comment: What are the valid types of `Read`?

Comment: ToExpression should never be used on user input, as it can execute arbitrary code: it's a huge unnecessary security risk.

Comment: Note, that this opens as many streams as the numbers you have (check with `Streams[]`) that are not closed.

Comment: @IstvánZachar    good call, I never noticed that..  See edit

Answer (score 10):

The intrinsic function `ToExpression` will convert its argument to an expression; if the argument is the string representation of a number the function will return the number.

These days (early 2023) there are other ways to convert a number string to a number. For example

```
Interpreter["Number"]["4.1234"]
```

ought to return the number `4.1234`, and ought to fail when the string can't be parsed as a number.  This approach makes it more difficult for arbitrary code to execute.

Comment: This method has the potential to execute arbitrary code if taking input from an untrusted source.

Comment: Yes, evaluating a totally general expression to get a number is an insane and unnecessary security risk. Crazy that there is not an in-built function to convert a string to a number!